# simple for loop error from edabit for loop returning undefined

Tags: loops

I don't know what is wrong with my for loop in javascript. Can someone please point out my mistake?

```js
function isFourLetters(arr) {
    let newArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i].length === 4){
            newArray.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you forget to return `newArray`? What the function should do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were just missing `return newArray;` in your function.

Here's a runnable example of your code with `return newArray;` added inside the function:

```js
function isFourLetters(arr) {
    let newArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i].length === 4){
            newArray.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArray; // This is the value that the function returns when called
}

let exampleArray1 = ["abc", "abcd", "abcde", "bcde"];
let exampleArray2 = ["wxy", "wxyz", "xyz", "test"];

console.log(isFourLetters(exampleArray1));
console.log(isFourLetters(exampleArray2));
```